# Could you support IDN for profile site?

Tags: support, feature-request, profile-page, hyperlinks

Could Stack Overflow support IDN (International Domain Names) in the profile's Web Site?
Currently, if you input an IDN, non-ASCII characters will simply not be saved (without warning): `tpî.eu` becomes `tp.eu`
So all I can do is use the equivalent punycode: `xn--tp-rja.eu` which is not so great.

Comment: I think a warning may be suitable, but a full implementation of IDN (Which I believe would include righ-to-left arabic for instance) may be too much effort for too little value.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin That probably requires one or two lines of code to be changed and maybe one configuration line https://www.punycoder.com/c-sharp/ if that's too much effort I don't know what isn't.

Comment: This also permits emoji, so it has broad utility.

Comment: uh oh, no emoji please, not on Stack Overflow.  That's just a mess waiting to happen.  ☹☹☹   

Comment: but what if your project is .la ? it is one hell of a PoC for emoji domains.

Comment: Hi All, I'm just asking for more chars allowed in urls. That can be done two ways: either by allowing specific chars (on demand, start with î, and I'll be glad) or by supporting punycode, and there again, you could restrict the range of Unicode chars accepted to something below Unicode emoji code (not sure if there is a start code for emoji though)